# TypeError: fetch failed [NextJS API]

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api

I always get ***error - TypeError: fetch failed*** after 300s when trying to request an optimization server which takes more than 300 seconds to respond.

I am sending this request from the API provided in NextJS.

Do you know how I can change the default timeout of 300 seconds?

This is the code:

```
// Setting request timeout
const OPTIMIZATION_TIMEOUT = 3600000 // 1 hour
const controller = new AbortController();
const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), OPTIMIZATION_TIMEOUT);

const omURL = formulasURL + "optimize/resourceallocationmt";
const omResponse = await fetch(omURL, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(optimization_data),
    signal: controller.signal
})
clearTimeout(timeoutId);
const omData = await omResponse.json();
```

[This is the error message which appears in the terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCCxo.png)

Answer (score 0):

have you verified that the request actually gets processed by the web api you're trying to reach? type error usually suggests it's a cors issue.

If you have you could try changing the way your web api works, with 300 seconds plus you should probably consider using something like long polling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes the web API works and is still processing the request while the error occurs. But it is a good point maybe long polling is a good solution to this problem.